# Selecting class name by partial match

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script where I select item values onclick() from a selector like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="bkLst" class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item bk7">ABC</div>
    <div class="dropdown-item bk65">XYZ</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const bk = document.querySelectorAll("#bkLst div");
        
bk.forEach(el => {
   el.addEventListener("click", () => {
   let bn = el.textContent;

  ...
```

I also need to select the name of the class for that item that starts with *bk*, as in *bk7*.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS!

You're looking for a [CSS Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

- `[class^="bk"]` targets an element where the first classname starts with "bk"
- `[class*=" bk"]` targets an element that has a classname starting with "bk" that follows other classnames.

```css
[class^="bk"], [class*=" bk"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="bkLst" class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item bk7">ABC</div>
    <div class="dropdown-item not-really-bk">DEF</div>
    <div class="dropdown-item bk65">XYZ</div>
    <div class="dropdown-item notbk">LMNOP</div>
    <div class="bk9000">QRSTUV</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will incorrectly select `class="notbk abc"` and `class="not-really-bk"` since it only checks if `bk` is included.

Comment: Good call @vera. I've updated the answer to handle those situations.

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't have a syntax for that (see the selectors spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors)). You can query based on an attribute starting with X, but class names may not be at the beginning of the `class` attribute.

Your best bet is to use a common class on them, adding it if necessary. For instance, in your example all of the `div` elements with those classes also have `dropdown-item` and there are no other `dropdown-item` elements in that parent, so you could use that. E.g.:

```
const bk = document.querySelectorAll("#bkLst .dropdown-item");
```

If there may be other `.dropdown-item` matches, add your own class:

```
<div id="bkLst" class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item your-class bk7">ABC</div>
    <div class="dropdown-item your-class bk65">XYZ</div>
</div>
```

and then

```
const bk = document.querySelectorAll("#bkLst .your-class");
```

In the worst case, if you can't modify the HTML and *have* to work from those partial class names, you can filter the result you get from `querySelectorAll`:

```
const bk = [...document.querySelectorAll("#bkLst div")]
    .filter(el => el.className.split(" ").some(n => n.startsWith("bk")));
```

Note that that gives you an array rather than a `NodeList`. How it works:

- `[...document.querySelectorAll("#bkLst div")]` gets all of the `div` elements in `#bkLst` and converts the `NodeList` to an array via iteration.
- `el.className.split(" ")` splits the `className` (reflected `class` attribute) on spaces, giving an array of the result.
- `.some(n => n.startsWith("bk"))` sees if any entry in the array starts with `bk`
- `.filter` keeps only the entries where `.some` returned `true`.

Comment: *(Oops, editing error. If you see `.your-class` in the code block with `filter`, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Oh this is an interesting solution, thanks. I was hoping to minimize my code and to make use of what I have. Alternatively I can just put the same bk22 class into data attribute or even id and grab it that way, I suppose. But thanks for the detailed write-up, makes me think in broader terms. Cheers.

Comment: @santa - I didn't get your `data-` attribute thing at first, but yeah, that would work: `<div data-example="bk7">...</div><div data-example="bk65">...</div>` then `querySelectorAll("#bkLst [data-example^=bk]")`.